# Pull to refresh returns the first position of the list

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, pull-to-refresh

I have one problem with pull to refresh, I use com.handmark.pulltorefresh. And I need to add new elements to this list when I see the last element of the list. I make this:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_generalnews, container,
                    false);
            mPullRefreshListView = (PullToRefreshListView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.pull_refresh_list2);

....
// Add an end-of-list listener
            mPullRefreshListView
                    .setOnLastItemVisibleListener(new OnLastItemVisibleListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onLastItemVisible() {
                            if (GeneralActivity.razr <= 7.0) {
                                pagenumber += 1;
                                Log.d("Menu", "Page2 = " + pagenumber);
                                newpage = "page/" + pagenumber + "/";
                                final int position = mPullRefreshListView.getRefreshableView().getFirstVisiblePosition()+1;
                                new MyTask().execute();
                                Log.d("List", "position of list = " + position);
                                mPullRefreshListView.onRefreshComplete();
                                mPullRefreshListView.post(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        mPullRefreshListView.getRefreshableView().setSelection(position);
                                        kfulist.setSelection(position);
                                    }
                                });
                                Log.d("List", "List " + kfunews.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

In MyTask() in onPostExecute I refresh adapter:

```
kfulist = mPullRefreshListView.getRefreshableView();
                    kfulist.setAdapter(newsadapter);
                    kfulist = mPullRefreshListView.getRefreshableView();

                    // Need to use the Actual ListView when registering
                    // for Context Menu
                    registerForContextMenu(kfulist);
                    newsadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

when I get to the end of the list, then it is updated and add new elements, but then returns to the first element of the list. And I can not understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are talking about an **AsyncTask** here. As it's asynchronous, when `mPullRefreshListView.onRefreshComplete()` appends afer the execution of the task, this task is in fact not yet finished.

You should add in `onPostExecute` everything you want to do affecting the UI (`onPostExecute` is executed in the UI thread)

Try this :

```
public void onPostExecute(**whatever the parameter**)
```

{
        kfulist = mPullRefreshListView.getRefreshableView();
        kfulist.setAdapter(newsadapter);
        // Useless
        // kfulist = mPullRefreshListView.getRefreshableView();

```
    // Need to use the Actual ListView when registering
    // for Context Menu
    registerForContextMenu(kfulist);
    newsadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Log.d("List", "position of list = " + position);
    mPullRefreshListView.onRefreshComplete();
    mPullRefreshListView.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            mPullRefreshListView.getRefreshableView().setSelection(position);
            kfulist.setSelection(position);
        }
    });
    Log.d("List", "List " + kfunews.toString());     

    // [...]
}
```